# After wordpress update in dashboard page content is not showing

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have update wordpress4.5 current version.After wordpress update in dashboard page content is not showing.And also not accepting the custom css in theme. I checked the log no error is shown.

Comment: What do you mean by "page content is not showing"? What is showing instead?

Comment: while editing the page the content is not showing i am using visual composer. In that I have classic mode and backend mode. Backend mode is shown all content. But the classic mode is not showing content.

Comment: when i turn on the debug and xdebug it shows me this error `
Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in LayerSlider_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
__construct()
instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3718`

Answer (score 0):

You need to update to the latest visual composer, there was a bug with 4.5 and has since been fixed.